# How to create a Photo Gallery on Android?

Tags: android, image-gallery

I want to create a photo gallery on Android. I'm using `Gallery` and `BaseAdapter` to create a scrollable gallery. Now I want to add an action when an image of the gallery is shown (each image's width is the same as screen width), so I need to get its index in the image array. My question is **how to get the index of the image** which shows on the screen?

I want to get the index of the image as soon as it shows on the screen, not on click event.
I've tried to get current image position in `getView()`, but the result is strange:

I scroll to image02 but position=2 (should be 1). When I scroll back, image02's position=0 (should be 1).

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);       

        Gallery g = (Gallery) this.findViewById(R.id.Gallery);  
        g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  

    private Context mContext;  
    private Integer[] mImageIds = {  
            //each image's size is 320x60
            R.drawable.btm01,  
            R.drawable.btm02,  
            R.drawable.btm03
    };  
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){  
        this.mContext = c;  
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mImageIds.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);  
        imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);  
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(320,60));    
        return imageView;  
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Gallery1.html) example.

```
// Reference the Gallery view
Gallery g = (Gallery) this.findViewById(R.id.Gallery);  
// Set the adapter to our custom adapter (below)
g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

// Set a item click listener, and just Toast the clicked position
g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(Gallery1.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: I want to get the image's index as soon as it shows, not on click event. Is that possible?

Comment: I think the index should be returned from something like onScroll event. But I can't find any function to use.

Comment: @iPhoney: What you need that for? It doesn't make any sense to me but you can use `position` in the `getView()` method.

Comment: In short, I want to inform user that image[0x] is shown as soon as it appears in the screen. Not when the user click on it. So I'm seeking for something like "scrollDidEndAtIndex(int index)".

Comment: oh, animations in `ListViews` and `Galleries` is something in my TODO list. This is a simple example I made: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12706953/ListTest.zip

Comment: Can BaseAdapter post a scroll finish event and pass the current index of image to me? Am I using the wrong classes to write this progaram?

Comment: It will call the `getView` method for the last item but it would be kind of a hack. The one who know when the scroll finished is the `ListView`, but I don't know if there is a method to pass a callback for that action. Sorry.